# CURL is not properly fetching the data from a site

Tags: php, curl

Im fetching the data from a site `www.example.com`.The data is in table like structure and there is also a pagination for that.im getting first page data properly and for fetching next pages data im running my code in `forloop`.i know total no pages which will be 3.My code is as follows :-

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/browseall";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
foreach($html->find('div.full_listing_pager') as $pages)
{
    $page = $pages->children(2)->plaintext;
}
curl_close($ch);
$limit = $page+1;

echo "limit--->".$limit;


echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Listing Id </th>";
echo "<th>Free Km Allowed</th>";
echo "<th>Free Days allowed</th>";
echo "<th>Driver requirements</th>";
echo "<th>Owner comments</th>";
echo "</tr>";


for($i=1;$i<$limit+1;$i++) //$limit =3(no of pages)
{
    $url=urlencode('http://www.example.com.au/browseall?browse_filter[from_city]=0&browse_filter[to_city]=0&browse_filter[car]=0&browse_filter[by_date]=0&page='.$i);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    foreach($html->find('table.full_listings_table tbody tr.more_info_second') as $div)
    {
        $str = "<tr>";

        $data = $div->find('td p b',0)->plaintext;
        $str .="<td>".$data."</td>";

        $data = $div->find('td div b',0)->plaintext;
        $str .="<td>".$data."</td>";

        $data = $div->find('td br b',0)->plaintext;
        $str .="<td>".$data."</td>";

        $data = $div->find('td div',0)->plaintext;
        $dataLen = strlen($data);
        $temp = "Driver requirements:";
        $tempLen = strlen($temp);
        $pos = strpos($data,$temp,0);

        $sum = $pos + $tempLen;
        $finalData = substr($data,$sum,$dataLen-$sum);

        $str .="<td>".$finalData."</td>"; 

        $data = $div->find('td div',2)->plaintext;
        $data = str_replace("Owner comments:"," ",$data);
        $str .="<td>".$data."</td>"; 

        echo $str."</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
curl_close($ch);
```

Problem is im getting the first page data 3 times .I want all 3 pages data in a table.Is there is something wrong in my code ?please help me on this, im new to `cURL`.

Comment: There's all kinds of wrong in your code example. Where does `$html` come from and what is it? Judging from the css selector you are passing into `find()` you are selecting a `<tr>` element yet your variable is called `$div`, is that intentional?

Comment: code is edited please refer that

Comment: Look in the loop: you are loading the new page into `$output`, but you're never moving it to `$html`

Comment: but its works fine for me but now i got 2 page data but not full data,im getting 1st page data and 2 page half data,I want all 3 page data.I donno know where im getting wrong please help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

God finally got the solution ...really im such an idiot i wrote

`$url=urlencode('http://www.example.com.au/browseall?browse_filter[from_city]=0&browse_filter[to_city]=0&browse_filter[car]=0&browse_filter[by_date]=0&page='.$i);`

there is no need of using urlencode.Now by writing this following code i got my solution:-

```
$url='http://www.example.com.au/browseall?browse_filter[from_city]=0&browse_filter[to_city]=0&browse_filter[car]=0&browse_filter[by_date]=0&page='.$i;
```